# Класс для перечисления с заданным типом C++

Tags: c++, qt, boost

Если в С++ сделать

```
enum operation = {plus, minus, mult, div};
```

То перечисляемые константы буду иметь тип operation.

А если мне нужно, чтобы переменная operation была типа char, и могла принимать только значения {'+', '-', '*', '/'} ?

Есть ли в std/Qt/boost/другой библиотеке какой-либо контейнер, который позволяет делать что-то в духе:

```
Enumeration<char> operation = {'+', '-', '*', '/'};
```

Или необходимо писать велосипед самому? Может, что-то есть на эту тему из области шаблонов проектирования?

Upd:
Или, еще лучше, если перечисляемые значения могут быть разного типа. К примеру, при разборе строки с арифметическим выражением на токены, токен может быть типов Operator, Operand или Bracket. Как-то так:

```
Enumeration<Operator, Operand, Bracket> Token = {op, num, br};
```

Comment: Для уточнения - шаблоны проектирования это совсем другое, они никак не относятся к шаблонам С++. Если хотите узнать про них больше - то почитайте "банду четырёх".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нет, ни в C++, ни в boost&Qt такого контейнера нет. Нет его по одной простой причине — в C++ нет одного общего типа как, скажем в C#&Java. Поэтому, просто невозможно создать контейнер, который будет принимать разнородные данные. Можно, конечно, создать `std::vector<boost::any>`(`QList<QVariant>` и вариации) но это, мягко говоря, не лучшее решение, т.к. всё равно придётся «помнить», что там за данные, иначе извлечь их не получится.

Поэтому, такие задачи решаются введением одного общего предка, а все вариации являются его наследниками. Создаётся контейнер указателей на этого предка и в него помещаются нужные потомки. К примеру, у Вас может быть `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AbstractOperation>> vec;` и в него Вы будете помещать Ваши конкретные объекты:

```
vec.push_back(std::make_shared<Operand>());
```

Но лучше это всё вынести в ещё одну абстракцию, которая будет представлять собой контейнер, а не использовать «голый» вектор.

Вообще, это довольно обширная тема, которую в рамках ответа не так просто и раскрыть.

---

Но если просто взять Ваш пример из вопроса, то его можно легко написать так:

```
std::tuple<Operator, Operand, Bracket> Token = std::make_tuple(op, num, br);
```

Хотя, я полагаю, Вам всё же нужен будет более широкий функционал и динамизм, который не достижим с помощью `std::tuple`. Если моё предположение верно, то для Вас подходит первая часть ответа.

Answer (score 10):

Вашу проблему касательно `char` можно решить достаточно просто: хранить коды символов в самом `enum`'e (ведь базовым типом перечисления может быть любой целочисленным тип, т.е. `int`, `long`, `char` и некоторые другие), а затем при обращении к элементам перечисления делать явное приведение к `char`:

```
enum CharEnum: char
{
   plus  = '+',
   minus = '-',
   mult  = '*',
   div   = '/'
};

int main()
{
   std::cout << static_cast<char>(CharEnum::plus);
}
```

---

Стоит заметить, что начиная с `C++11` появился `enum class` (можно писать и  `enum struct`, что то же самое), который обладает рядом преимуществ перед обычным `enum`:

- не экспортирует свои значения в окружающую область видимости, что могло бы приводить к конфликтам имен
- отсутствует неявное преобразование значений перечислимого типа к целочисленным типам как у обычного `enum`, что могло бы приводить к ошибкам

Таким образом, в предыдущем примере достаточно поменять `enum` на `enum class`, а весь остальный синтаксис останется неизменным.

Comment: Хотя это правда, начиная с С++11 можно использовать enum class, только вот это ничего не меняет в этой задаче. Совершенно. Он тут не нужен(не является обязательным)

Comment: @ixSci Да, но я ведь в конце ответа указал на это.

Comment: Просто в начале ответа Вы указываете на появление enum class, как будто он что-то меняет в данном случае. Можно убрать слово class из кода и всё остальное останется прежним.

Comment: @ixSci Убедили, переформулировал ответ :)

Comment: Для задания базового типа перечисления НЕ НУЖНО иметь именно `enum class`, достаточно просто `enum`.

Comment: @alexolut А вот это внезапно, честно говоря, не знал :)

Comment: Кстати, для варианта без `class` можно и разрешение имени опустить. Хотя, в случае переезда на `class` менять меньше, но с другой стороны кому-то может показаться что `CharEnum::plus` это не просто `plus`.